# Bitwise AND not calculating the expected value

Tags: c++, vector, bitwise-operators

What am I missing here?

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uint16_t week = 900;
    std::vector <uint8_t>out;

    out.push_back(0x00ff & week);
    out.push_back(0xff00 & week);

    for (int i = 0; i < out.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << (int)out[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**expected output**

84
03

**actual output**

84
00

Comment: `0xff00 & week` isn't going to fit into a `uint8_t` value (which your container stores).

Comment: so I need to shift it right 8. damn how did I miss that

Comment: `week & 0xff00 == 300` - `3` is cut of as @IInspectable explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitwise AND **is** calculating the correct value. There is nothing wrong with the expression `0xff00 & week`, it produces the value `0x0300` (with `week` being 900). The value gets truncated when it's moved into the container, that can only store values of type `uint8_t`.

To store the upper byte of a `uint16_t`, you'll have to shift it right:

```
out.push_back(0x00ff & week);
out.push_back(0x00ff & (week >> 8));
```

Comment: You are correct. Stupid mistake. Thanks for the extra eye.